# Stream multiple files over HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

My application need to transfer multiple files to an http server (by opening OutputStream from HttpUrlConnection) but to avoid overhead of connection establishment we would like to use one connection only. Would this be feasible?

Note: The data is created in real time so that we cannot add them into one archive file and transfer with one shot.

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're over-optimizing. `HttpURLConnection` already does TCP connection pooling behind the scenes. Just use a new `URL,` `HttpURLConnection`, `OutputStream`, etc., per file.

Comment: Thanks EJP! Could you please explain a bit about the TCP connection pool? (pool size, time out, etc.). Is it possible to control this pool? Is the TCP connection be pooled if we call UrlConnection.disConnect() after each transferring?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have to output more than one file does not prevent the fact that you can still use an archive format which can be created using your `OutputStream`, in real time; and zip is such a format.

The JDK has [`ZipOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) which can help you there; basically you can use it as such (code to set the HTTP headers not shown):

```
// out is your HttpUrlConnection's OutputStream

try (
    final ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(out);
) {
    addEntries(zout);
}
```

The `addEntries()` method would then create `ZipEntry` instances, one per file, and write the contents.

Comment: Thank fge! Actually the data is already written to GZIPOutputStream directly. The result file at destination will be <file_name>.tar.gz. The problem here is that data comes after a period (1 file every 5min) and we need to stream it immediately.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Apache [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). It supports HTTP 1.1 keep-alive feature.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

Fast read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: So does `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. There's no need to go outside the JDK for this.